# Customize figure name (just as chapter name) in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

Bookdown [allows the customization](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html) of chapter names, which is handy when a Hungarian project is built, as `Chapter 1` is translated as `1. fejezet` (i.e. the renaming of `Chapter` is not enough).

However, the very same is true for figure (and table) names as well, because `Figure 1.1` should be translated as `1.1. ábra`, but I don't know how to achieve this (`_bookdown.yml` doesn't seem to support something like "`language/ui/figure_name`" just as it does with `chapter_name`).

There is no problem with the PDF (LaTeX) output, because including `\usepackage[magyar]{babel}` in the `preamble.tex` solves this problem, but I don't know what to do with the non-PDF formats, where my only idea was to use the `_bookdown.yml`.

Comment: Are your generating LaTeX or non-LaTeX-output?

Comment: @ekstroem Both of them! (I render it to all format, ie. to gitbook, pdf_book and epub_book as well.)

Comment: @ekstroem I just realized that there is no problem with the LaTeX output, because including `\usepackage[magyar]{babel}` solves this. I updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The `bookdown.yml` modifications to `"language/language/label"` should affect output to HTML such as gitbook. For example setting the following in `bookdown.yml` will give Danish labels:

```
book_filename: "mybook"
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: "Kapitel "
    appendix_name: "Appendiks "
  label:
    fig: 'Figur '
    tab: 'Tabel '
```

For LaTeX output you should redefine the labels in the `in_header` file specified for your pdf output in the `_output.yml` file. For example, if your `_output.yml` file looks like this

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  highlight: default
  includes:
    in_header: latex/preamble.tex
```

then you can redefine the labels in the `latex/preamble.tex` file. Include the following line in that file to rename the figure labels.

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figur}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately that's not a solution here. Like I have written, the problem is specifically that the translated label should go _after_ the number in Hungarian! That's why language/ui/chapter_name is perfect (I can use `!expr function(i) paste( i, ". fejezet")`), but a simple renaming doesn't help.

Comment: Ah yes. See what you mean. And inserting a function for `fig` doesn't work either as it did for the chapter name (and I'm sure you already tried that as well). probably need Yihui to weigh in